# React Native View Render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rendering, react-native

how can I render views conditionally? Example: if my app has not connected to internet - render error view, if connected - render WebView? Does that possible with react native? I want to render  not pure html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Logic to render views conditionally, using your example:

```
render() {
  if (!this.state.isConnected) { // error
    return (
      <View></View>
    );
  }
  else {
    return ( // webview
      <WebView />
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In your render method , you can define conditionals like the example below. For instance, you may check your connection at componentDidMount method and then set your props.

```
 render(){
          if(this.state.isConnected == 'Online' )
            return this.webView();
          else
            return this.renderAnotherView();
        }
```

Comment: This method did not show any veiw. I got props for online and offline, I just want to this.state.isConnected == 'Online' - show webview, if offline - show another veiw

Comment: this.props.hasConnection was just an example. You may check your connectivity and return your webView or some other view you defined

Answer (score 0):

If it's specific to the WebView, this component contains two render functions.

> **renderError** function
>
> Function that returns a view to show if there's an error.
>
> **renderLoading** function
>
> Function that returns a loading indicator.
>
> [WebView Component Docs.](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview.html#content)

With renderError function you can return a view indicated there's an error  including the app is not connected to the internet.